# Pandas regex extract creates multiple column

Tags: regex, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df1` with the following rows:

```
df1['col1']

asd1 12KVsdf
pqr 11.2 KVsdf
```

I am trying the following:

```
df1['col1'].extract(r'(\d*\.\d+\sKV)|(\d+\sKV)')
```

This gives:

```
df1['col1']

  0   1
12KV  NaN
NaN   11.2 KV
```

I am trying to extract all numerals immediately preceding KV.

My desired output is:

```
df1['col1']

  0   
12KV
11.2 KV
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
df1['col2'] = df1['col1'].str.extract(r'(\d*\.?\d+\s?KV)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qWzPmC/2). Note the `\s` is made optional, and the number matching pattern is changed to match both integer and float values.

*Details*

- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.`
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `KV` - `KV` literal text.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 capture groups (stuff between parentheses), thats why you are getting 2 columns.

You could put it all in just one capture group so you will only get 1 column:

```py
df1['col1'].extract(r'(\d*\.\d+\sKV|\d+\sKV)')
```

Any way, that regexp could be definetively improved as Wiktor Stribiżew suggested in his answer.

Comment: If you need to group something, but not capturing it, you should use a "non capturing group" just placing ``?:`` after the opening parenthesis: ``(?:i'm a not capturing group)``.